# Accessing Api's from within container in EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm new in AWS and EC2, I created a very simple hello world node.js application and dockerized it and I'm able to access the api route from within the container in my local machine, then I deployed the docker image to the docker hub and pulled that image from an EC2 instance and ran the image the docker logs shows that container is running fine.
[image]

Then from the EC2 instance information I get the

```
IPv4 Public IP xx.xxx.x.xxx
```

From the browser I try going to `http://xx.xxx.x.xxx:8080/`
but it times out and can't be reached, I'm expecting to see the hello world.
wonder if I'm missing any thing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't whitelisted your IP! AWS resources by default will block unknown incoming requests. To allow your machine to access to the EC2 you have to add it's IP address to your EC2's security group.

Comment: I set it to from anywhere and now I can see the Congratulations page on port 80 but my app is exposed on port 8080 and in the inbound rules port 8080 can't be set, I used custom tcp rules and set it to 8080 but still it shows me the congratulation page how can I can see my hello world page?

Comment: First of all, it's really not good practice to allow access from anywhere, especially when you post your public IP to stack overflow. It would be quite easy to exploit your server and you should really remove your IP from your post. Secondly, you certainly can set specific port access in the inbound rules, check the AWS documentation, I have done it many times!

Comment: Thanks @ArloClark Thanks for your tip, though the server is only for test, but still I see only the Congratulation page.